# How to set return array user into response laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
<?php

foreach($users as $user) {
    $user = User::create(array(
        'user_id' => $user['user_id'],
        'user_text' => "1",
        'other_id' => $user['other_id']
    ));
}

return Response::json(['success' => true, 'message' => 'successfully', 'data' => $user], 201);
```

How can i send multiple created users into the response it does not allow me setting user into data key please guide even i tried to set return response inside the loop it does allow only only value to set.

Comment: after formatting, i found some syntax errors in your code. please check the foreach loop correctly

Comment: You're setting `'data' => $user` which is only set inside your `foreach`. Maybe try `$users` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach( $users as $user ) {
                        $send_user[] = User::create(array('user_id' => $user['user_id'], 'user_text' => "1", 'other_id' => $user['other_id']));

                    }   
    return Response::json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'successfully',
            'data' => $send_user
        ], 200);
```

Comment: change your `$user[]` to something `$createdUsers` and define this as array at top of foreach, because `$user` has already defined

Comment: Okay i was declaring this $send_user[] outside foreach thanks

Answer (score 1):

return response()->json(['type'=>'success','data'=>$user], 200);

Comment: @langer if it works then please mark it as an answer so that it will also useful to others.